# how to make an appending input and send value to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I want to know how to make a button that makes a new `<input>` everytime user clicks it and I want its value to be added to an array.

I used this code that I found but it only does the first part!

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, FormInput } from "shards-react";
  
class Parameter extends React.Component {
  
    id = 1;
  
      state = {
          list: []
      }
      
      item(id) {
          return (
            //   <div >

            //       <i className="material-icons" onClick={e => this.remove(`${id}`)} >delete</i>

            //   </div>);
            <FormInput className="mb-1" key={id} id={`param-${id}`} placeholder="Competetion parameters"/>
            );
      }
  
      remove(id) {
          const newList = this.state.list.filter(item =>item.key !== id);
          this.setState({
              list: newList
          })
      }
  
      addParam = () => {
        
          const list = this.state.list;
          list.push( this.item(this.id) )
          this.setState({ list });
          this.id++;
      }
  
      render() {
  
          return (
              <div>
                  <Button onClick={e => this.addParam()} theme="primary">Add parameter</Button>
                  {
                      this.state.list.map(item => item)
                  }
              </div>);
      }
    
  }
  
  export default Parameter;
```

I want to know how can I put a group of input values, to an array
React is really new to me, id be very happy if someone could help me with this!

Comment: Hi! As it is, your question is really unclear. Please first format your question (fix code style, such as indentation levels) and removing the unnecessary bits.. also either add your entire component or just the relevant parts. After that, please read your question again and see for yourself is it clear what you are asking and if you could clarify it a bit :)

Comment: There are even some syntax issues (see setLoading) in your example code

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I made it more clear, is it ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how to make a button that makes a new  every time user clicks it and I want its value to be added to an array and post it with Axios.

It feels there are two questions in one here; first is how to deal with the state (amount of inputs) and second how to save the array.

I can't really help with the second one without examining how setLoading exactly works, but I have a suggestion for dealing with the state. Add each input value as a string into an array and do something like this:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  const { useState } = React;

  function Boxes() {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);

    const addInput = () => {
      setInputs(inputs.concat("abc"));
    };

    const changeInput = (index, value) => {
      const updated = [...inputs];
      updated[index] = value;
      setInputs(updated);
    };

    const handleAdd = () => {
      alert("Saving " + JSON.stringify(inputs));
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <p>inputs</p>
        {inputs.map((input, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}><input
              type="text"
              value={input}
              onChange={(e) => changeInput(index, e.target.value)}
            /></div>
          );
        })}
        <button onClick={addInput}>Add new input</button>
        <hr />
        <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<Boxes />, document.querySelector("#root"));
};
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question again so only show the problem of arrays. how can I call the array?